# How to prove equality between this integral over an $n$-dimensional space and the reciprocal factorial?

Tags: integration, combinatorics

## Context

### Where does this question come from?

I'm reading from [*Introduction to Mathematical Statistics, 3rd Edition* by Robert Hogg and Allen Craig](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005EENJ1O), which came into my posession when I professor was giving away books at the time of his retirement from my alma mater. While more [recent editions of this book exist](https://www.amazon.ca/Introduction-Mathematical-Statistics-Robert-Hogg/dp/0134686993), this one kind of fell into my path. My question pertains to Example 7 of Chapter 1:

> Let $A$ be a set in $n$-dimensional space and let $$Q(A)=\int_A \dots \int dx_1 dx_2 \dots x_n$$. If $$A = \{ (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n); 0\leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \dots \leq x_n \leq 1 \}$$, then $$Q(A)=\int_0^1 \int_0^{x_n} \dots \int_0^{x_3} \int_0^{x_2} dx_1 dx_2 \dots dx_{n-1} dx_n = \frac{1}{n!}$$.

### My work on the problem

I've been reading the book from front-to-back, so some of the prework up to this problem was reading what the authors had to say before they gave Example 7. I've also looked back through the little material that has been covered up to this example within the book, and I didn't feel that there was sufficient detail given for me to prove this equality.

While not sufficient to prove the equality, Example 6 on page 9 from the same book/chapter helped me understand example 7 as it is similar in concept.

> Example 6. Let $A$ be a one-dimensional set and let $$Q(A)=\int_A e^{-x} dx$$. Thus, if $$A = \{ x; o \leq x < \infty \}$$, then $$Q(A)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} dx = 1$$; if $$A = \{ x; 1 \leq x \leq 2 \}$$, then $$Q(A)=\int_1^2 e^{-x} dx = e^{-1} - e^{-2}$$; if $$A_1 = \{ x; 0 \leq x \leq 1 \}$$ and $$A_2 = \{ x; 1 < x \leq 3 \}$$, then $$Q(A_1 \cup A_2) = \int_0^3 e^{-x} dx = \int_0^1 e^{-x} dx + \int_1^3 e^{-x} dx = Q(A_1) + Q(A_2)$$; if $$A = A_1 \cup A_2$$, where $$A_1 = \{ x; 0 \leq x \leq 2 \}$$ and $$A_2 = \{ x; 1 \leq x \leq 3 \}$$, then $$Q(A) = Q(A_1 \cup A_2) = \int_0^3 e^{-x} dx = \int_0^2 e^{-x} dx + \int_1^3 e^{-x} dx - \int_1^2 e^{-x} dx = Q(A_1) + Q(A_2) - Q(A_1 \cap A_2)$$

Reading Example 6, it was not a surprise to me how set theory works or how to evaluate definite integrals of $e^{-x}$, but it was having to account for overcounting in the final case of the example where they explicitly mention subtracting the integral of the intersection. I definitely had one of those "I'm surprised I didn't see that coming" moments when I realized how set theory was being simply applied here. I feel I should have known better since I did well in my integral calculus course (undergraduate) a few years ago, but I come by it honestly. What I learned from Example 6 is that I need to think carefully about the set definition in Example 7.

In Example 7, unlike Example 6, the inequalities in the set definition are comparing the values of different variables rather than having an overlap of sets in describing the same variable. So I think this means I can attempt to integrate without accounting for over/undercounting. When I first saw Example 7, I thought I might need to use the Inclusion/Exlusion Principle but I no longer think that it is needed here in the way that it could be applied to Example 6.

Something that is unusual about this integral is that the integration upper bounds $x_n$ are paired with the differential $x_{n-1}$ with the exception of the outmost bounds from zero to one integrated with respect to $dx_n$.

Since Example 7 does not explicitly mention the integrand, this is generally considered the constant function $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) = 1$. I will assume that convention is followed.

The first case of $n=1$ would be
$$Q(A) = \int_0^1 dx_1 = x_1]_0^1 = 1 - 0 = 1$$

which agrees with $\frac{1}{1!} = 1$.

The second case of $n=2$ would be

$$Q(A) = \int_0^1 \int_0^{x_2} dx_1 dx_2 = \int_0^1 x_2 dx_2 = \frac{1}{2}$$

which agrees with $\frac{1}{2!} = \frac{1}{2}$.

As mentioned in the comments, one approach would be to setup a proof by induction. The proposition is the integral described as Example 7. The base case would be the $n=1$ case that I described. I'm a little perplexed by doing the inductive step of showing that the $k$th case implies the $k+1$ case when there's dot notation.

Comment: Just a clarification in regard to asking good questions on math.SE: Yes, this comes from a textbook. No, this is not a homework problem.

Comment: I see that this question has been downvoted without comment. Please provide feedback when possible.

Comment: Let $F(t)=\int_0^t \int_0^{x_n} \dots \int_0^{x_3} \int_0^{x_2} dx_1 dx_2 \dots dx_{n-1} dx_n$. You can try to prove $F(t)=\frac{t^n}{n!}$ by induction for $n$.

Comment: Downvotes of perfectly acceptable questions without comment are increasingly becoming a scourge of this site. I upvoted to compensate.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need any calculus for this. The integration variables can have $n!$ different orders, and the volume of the unit hypercube in which they have a given order is the same for all these orders by symmetry, and thus $\frac1{n!}$. You’re integrating over the volume where they have one particular order.

Comment: That's interesting. Why do I need to consider all possible orders on the unit cube?

Comment: @Galen: I'm not sure I understand that question. It's not that you *need* to consider them. You can just carry out the integrals. But if you *do* consider them, you can see the symmetry between them and deduce that they must all correspond to the same fraction of the volume. There's no such thing as seeing the symmetry between them without considering all of them.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see that I wasn't be careful about my use of the word *need*. Point taken. I mostly understand, I am just struggling to find the right clarifying question to fill in the gap.

Comment: I can imagine the invariance of a unit hypercube's volume under permutation of the integration variables, and I understand that for $n$ variables there will be $n!$ arrangements of those variables. The last step that I'm trying to think through is why that implies the volume that is shared among them is $\frac{1}{n!}$. A unit cube's volume is 1, so I'm looking at this as the volume of a unit hypercube divided by the number of arrangments of the variables.

Comment: @Galen: What do you mean by "shared among them"?

Comment: I meant "shared among them" to refer to the definite integral being invariant under permutations of the integration variables.

Comment: @Galen: I'm thinking now that perhaps my formulation "the volume of the unit hypercube in which they have a given order" caused a misunderstanding. I should perhaps more clearly have written "the volume of the part of the unit hypercube in which they have a given order". All $n!$ orders are present in the unit hypercube, and the volume of the part of the unit hypercube in which the variables have a certain order is the same for all $n!$ permutations, and is thus $\frac1{n!}$. I hope that clears things up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107014/discussion-between-galen-and-joriki).