# How do I set up the bounds of integration of $Q(A_2) = \int_{A_2} \int (x^2 + y^2) dx dy$ over the set $A_2 = \{(x,y); -1 \leq x = y\leq 1 \}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

### Where this question comes from

I'm reading from [*Introduction to Mathematical Statistics, 3rd Edition* by Robert Hogg and Allen Craig](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005EENJ1O), which came into my posession when I professor was giving away books at the time of his retirement from my alma mater. While more [recent editions of this book exist](https://www.amazon.ca/Introduction-Mathematical-Statistics-Robert-Hogg/dp/0134686993), this one kind of fell into my path. I'm reading it to improve my own understanding of the mathematical underpinnings of statistics, and ultimately to help me understand the underpinnings of statistical machine learning. My question pertains to Exercise 1.12 of Chapter 1:

> Exercise 1.12 Let $$Q(A) = \int_A \int (x^2 + y^2) dx dy$$ for every two-dimensional set $A$ for which the integral exists; otherwise, let $Q(A)$ be undefined. If $$A_1 = \{(x,y); -1 \leq x \leq 1, -1 \leq y\leq 1 \}$$, $$A_2 = \{(x,y); -1 \leq x = y\leq 1 \}$$, and $$A_3 = \{(x,y); x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}$$, find $Q(A_1)$, $Q(A_2)$, and $Q(A_3)$

I've included the entire exercise for completeness, however I am only seeking assistance with setting up the integration bounds for $Q(A_2)$ in this post.

## My work on the problem

Beyond having read everything in the book that comes before this problem, understanding [all-but-one example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633903/how-to-prove-equality-between-this-integral-over-an-n-dimensional-space-and-th), and completing all the previous exercises, I've also formulated some thoughts on how to tackle this specific problem.

What's puzzling me about $Q(A_2)$ is that there $x=y$ is always in $[-1,1]$, which is a number I don't know. Can I just declare that there's an arbitray number $a$ as follows

$$Q(A_2) \stackrel{?}{=} \int_a^1 \int_{-1}^{a} (x^2 + y^2) dx dy$$

or is it equally or more valid to simply put either $x$ or $y$ in that place as I show below?

$$Q(A_2) \stackrel{?}{=} \int_y^1 \int_{-1}^{y} (x^2 + y^2) dx dy \stackrel{?}{=} \int_x^1 \int_{-1}^{x} (x^2 + y^2) dx dy$$

Note that I'm only asking about this step in setting up the integral. You can solve it in your answer if you want, but I will accept answers that simply deal with the notational confusion I just described.

I'm not a mathematician, so if I've blundered some terminology or other technical issue, please feel free to let me know in the comments how I can improve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral should be zero and you don't need to set up any bounds: the set $A_2$ is nothing but a line segment in a square.

[Added:]
The hint of your book (4th edition) says the following:

> [image]

Instead of trying to set bounds for the integral, you should go back to the definition of the double integrals as the hint suggested.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response! Perhaps I don't need to, but I would like to know how they would be setup even though the integral evaluates to zero. The purpose of my question is to better understand how to translate the set definition to the integral bounds. I appreciate you sharing your mathematical knowledge about the line segment.

Comment: @Galen: what edition is your book? Do you see the hint there?

Comment: Huh, that hint does not exist in my 3rd edition.